# Rest-Assured keep cookie OR Authorization header up to date

Tags: java, cookies, load-balancing, rest-assured, bearer-token

we using rest-assured in two situations where i can't find an automatic solution. i have a feeling i am missing something.

1#:

till now Rest-Assured was automatically updating the session value from the server. we recently moved to a new architecture that uses an load balancer. so the server is returning additionally to the old one, a new cookie representing the load balancer. i find my self getting the new cookie programmatically and updating the next requests.
can rest assured do the automatically for me ?

2#:

other servers require the header "Authorization: Bearer yada.yada.yada". to be renewed after each request.  Here also how can i tell rest-Assured to do that automatically for me ?

thank you 
shay

Comment: How are you getting new auth token? From last response?

Comment: yes, i am sending a "sign-in" request with key/secret. and getting a response of JWT. from this point any request will send back a new JWT in the header, and i need to send this token on my next request. my current solution is to update the header for the next request manually .

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [AuthFilter](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#custom-authentication) to automatically provide auth header to your requests. But you still need to extract data - do it with an additional filter:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.ResponseBuilder;
import io.restassured.filter.FilterContext;
import io.restassured.filter.OrderedFilter;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableResponseSpecification;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class ReuseRestAssuredResponse {

    private static String authVal = "default";

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        RestAssured.filters(new SetAuthFilter(), new GetAuthFilter());
        given()
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .get("https://httpbin.org/get")
                .then()
                .log().all();

        given()
                .log().all()
                .when()
                .get("https://httpbin.org/get")
                .then()
                .log().all();
    }

    class SetAuthFilter implements OrderedFilter {

        @Override
        public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification filterableRequestSpecification, FilterableResponseSpecification filterableResponseSpecification, FilterContext filterContext) {
            filterableRequestSpecification.header("Testauth", authVal);
            return filterContext.next(filterableRequestSpecification, filterableResponseSpecification);
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return DEFAULT_PRECEDENCE - 1;
        }
    }

    class GetAuthFilter implements OrderedFilter {

        @Override
        public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification filterableRequestSpecification, FilterableResponseSpecification filterableResponseSpecification, FilterContext filterContext) {
            Response response = filterContext.next(filterableRequestSpecification, filterableResponseSpecification);
            authVal = response.body().path("headers.Testauth") + "_updated";
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return DEFAULT_PRECEDENCE;
        }
    }

}
```

So... what's happing here?

First request will be made with header `Testauth=default` the second with `Testauth=default_updated`, and if you will add else one iteration it would be `Testauth=default_updated_updated`

Actually `GetAuthFilter` should be a little bit difficult to respect body expectations, see implementation of `io.restassured.filter.log.StatusCodeBasedLoggingFilter` which extract response data and prints it.

Also you may use `FilterContext` values storage to pass values between filters, external static variable is just to simplify example.